# NSXMLParser: How to extract a string with the tags and attributes untouched

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsxmlparser

I I'm doing something a bit strange. Is it possible to extract part of an XML file with XML parser without parsing it, and instead extract it as a string.

```
<root>
    <element>
      <don't parse>it amet, consectetur<tag> adipiscing</tah> elit. Vestibulum ac viverra nulla. Donec dapibus, eros dapibus eleifend aliquet, turpis nulla aliquam libero
      </don't parse> //resume parsing
    </element>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use CDATA tag

```
<root>
    <element>
      <![CDATA[
          <don't parse>it amet, consectetur<tag> adipiscing</tah> elit. Vestibulum ac viverra nulla. Donec dapibus, eros dapibus eleifend aliquet, turpis nulla aliquam libero
          </don't parse> //resume parsing
    ]]>
    </element>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks allot. I'm an XML noob.